# How to use "ReSharper.ReSharper_SilentCleanupCode" in a vs2010 macro?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, exception, macros, resharper

I am trying to build a macro that formats all modified files before saving them.

```
Public Module ReformatAndSave

Sub SingleFile()
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("ReSharper.ReSharper_SilentCleanupCode")
    DTE.ActiveDocument.Save()
End Sub

Sub AllFiles()
    For Each doc As Document In DTE.Documents
        If Not doc.Saved Then
            doc.Activate()
            DTE.ExecuteCommand("ReSharper.ReSharper_SilentCleanupCode")
            DTE.ActiveDocument.Save()
        End If
    Next
End Sub
End Module
```

This results in an error

> > Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

It works when I use this instead:

```
DTE.ExecuteCommand("ReSharper.ReSharper_CleanupCode")
```

I could live with this solution for a single file but choosing the profile when saving all files is annoying.

I use ReSharper 6.1.1000.82. This bug seems to be rather old: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-179846

Is it possible to work around this bug by collecting all modified files and the execute the working CleanUpCode command once for all the files. 
I can manually select many files and execute CleanUp on these files, manually. I would like to do this automatically on all modified files when saving them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is so simple.
All I had to do is replacing this

```
DTE.ExecuteCommand("ReSharper.ReSharper_CleanupCode")
```

with this

```
DTE.ExecuteCommand("ReSharper_SilentCleanupCode")
```

This doesn't work!

```
DTE.ExecuteCommand("ReSharper.ReSharper_SilentCleanupCode")
```